# Find the arc-length of the circle with radius a?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, conic-sections

Find the arc-length of a circle with radius a. 

From the equation of a circle, I found out the equation for the one quadrant, which is:
$y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$
I tried solving the problem, and here's what I did:
$$A = 4 \int_0^a \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2}}dx$$
$$A = 4 \int_0^a \frac{a}{\sqrt{{a^2-x^2}}}dx $$
 And this is where I need help. How can solve this integral now?

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:*** Fix the problem, it should be $y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ as i edited it. Then use the substitution $x=a\sin \theta$

Comment: How do you write integrals in here? Or what's the name of the language you write math in here? Where can I find more help on writing math formulas in this website?@Semsem

Comment: First write math using between $ signs, you can use [Latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Click on "help", it should lead you to links on how to write math on this site.